# Logging actual usage of modules in a growing code-base

Tags: python, optimization

A lot of production code is generated every week, some of them aren't used anymore, how can we identify those unpopular modules/snippets to prevent bloated code-base?

The only idea I came up with was to add `Decorators` to all our modules, (literally typing it) but that sounds like an overkill, or is it how it would be done?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How are you doing it right now? Does not using git/mercurial prevent this?

Comment: I've just tried it with little modules we have, basically added a `@logger` decorator, that anytime called creates an entry in a log file. That was the most basic idea i could imagine it to work.

Comment: You must prevent this in the first place.

Comment: True, but i cannot go back in time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a static analysis tool.  One of the things these (can) do, is flag unused blocks of code.  Typically, you can integrate it into your CI loop.

A quick search for 'python static analysis' on Google gives a number of links.  One curated list of tools for various languages is [here](https://github.com/mre/awesome-static-analysis).  One tool under `Python` that immediately jumps up for unused code checking is [vulture](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture), and it seems to be actively maintained.

Comment: I was concerned about static code analysis for python as python is `live` but vulture seems to be an interesting idea! But Apart from finding `unused` classes it would be interesting to see `least used` ones.

Comment: If you mean live, as in the code needs to run, static analysis is usually done statically (as opposed to dynamically for items like memory profiling, etc).

Comment: I think you'd have trouble with that one, since it's not objective.  Best bet might be to instrument your code with execution counters, and check those?

Comment: The other issue is that even though something might not be used /often/, it may still be crucial for your code to function, and those metrics would need to take this into account.  May I suggest code review ;-)

Comment: Haha code review is good, but if there wasn't a good code-review in place, someone has to clean it up first.

Comment: Code review is, ironically, good for cleaning up code :)  My approach with legacy code is to do it piece by piece, at regular intervals, until you're there.  Also, if someone 'touches' a section of code, make them responsible for checking and cleaning it up.  That's a potentially useful way to weed out sections of code that doesn't get used often.